# Sort(a,b) does not work in Dojo.dnd.source

Tags: javascript, sorting, dojo

I try to sort the data after user drop an element on target container, here is the sorting event

```
......
var elements_container= dojo.dnd.Source("elements_container");
dojo.byId("elements_container").innerHTML = '';

... // add elements into container...

function sortDnD(){
    // actually full class name is ".element dojoDndItem" to query
    dojo.query(".element",  dojo.byId("elements_container")).sort(
        function( a,b ) {  
            // fire bug debugging cursor skip this section
            var divs_a = dojo.query('&gt; div.sequence', a)
            var diValue_a = divs_a[0].innerHTML;
            var divs_b = dojo.query('&gt; div.sequence', b)
            var diValue_b = divs_b[0].innerHTML;
                return (divs_a == divs_b ? 0 : (a.divs_a > b.divs_b ? 1 : -1));
        }
    ).forEach(// fire bug debugging cursor move to this section
        function(a, idx) { 
            dojo.byId("element_container").insertBefore(a, dojo.byId("elements_container").childNodes[idx]);  
    });
}
```

dojo.byId("elements_container") is the dojo dnd source. I can guarantee that there are several elements in the containers...

I am using dojo1.6, interestingly when I debug by firebug, it looks the body inside of

```
function( a,b ) {  
    ....
}
```

never executed, nor get any error message; the debug cursor move to `.forEach` just after `function( a,b )` but the body of `.forEach` method runs without any problem. It looks the sort function give no response at all.

## UPDATE

here is the code to invoke above sorting function

```
dojo.connect( source_container, "onDndDrop", function( source, nodes, copy, target ) {
    nodes.forEach(function(node) {
         sortDnD();
    });
});
```

## UPDATE2

After I change

```
dojo.query(".element",  dojo.byId("elements_container")).sort(
```

to

```
dojo.query(".element",  elements_container).sort(
```

Dojo gives:

```
TypeError: root.getElementsByClassName is not a function
...ag){var ret=_201(0,arr),te,x=0;var tret=root.getElementsByClassName(_235);while(...
```

and here is the dom data for `elements_container`

```
node: div#elements_container.container.dnd-list.dojoDndContainer.dojoDndSource.dojoDndTarget
childrenNodes: NodeList[div#dojoUnique23.element.dojoDndItem, div#dojoUnique24.element.dojoDndItem, .....
```

Comment: How are you invoking sortDnD() ? I can't see a call to it in your code.

Comment: @Philippe Thanks. Just update the post, it is a very simple function to trigger the `onDndDrop` event listener, can run by fire bug without problem

Comment: The fact that your callback never gets executed suggests your dojo.query call returns an empty array. Can you paste the dom structure you are seeing in firebug ?

Comment: @Philippe Update again per your request, now I have some new finding..

Comment: I think you should use dojo.query(".element.dojoDndItem", "elements_container").sort(...

Comment: @Philippe yes that works and sir you are genius, please put it as answer I will close this thread :D thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the callback in the sort is not being called is because your query selector returns an empty array (therefore you have nothing to sort on).

Use the following instead :

```
dojo.query(".element.dojoDndItem", "elements_container").sort(
```

Note that initially your selector was ".element .dojoDndItem" which means "find all nodes with class dojoDndItem that are children of nodes with class element". Here, both classes are in the same nodes, so you need to remove the space and make the selector be ".element.dojoDndItem".